# Kendo UI Custom Pop-up Editor in Hierarchical Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Hierarchical grid and I'm trying to add a custom editor for pop-up editing.  When I add the template to the child grid and click on the "edit" button, i get a invalid template error.  If i add that same template to the parent, it works fine.

Here is the error in console:

Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'

Here is the code

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ParentViewModel>()
                  .Name("GridAdjax")
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .PageSize(20)
                      .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                      .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "controller"))
                      .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Id(c => c.Id);
                      })
                      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                      .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))

                  )
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyName).Title("Company Name");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyDomain).Title("Company Domain");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanySecurityRole).Title("Security Role");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanySecurityGroup).Title("Security Group");
                  })
                  .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                  .Pageable()
                  .Sortable()
                  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                  .Events(e => e.DataBound("OnDataBound"))
                  .Deferred()

                  )
<CHILD>
            <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ChildlViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=CompanyId#") 
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Update(update => update.Action("CompanyList_Update", "Administration"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Child", new { companyId = "#=CompanyId#" }))
                        .Model(model =>
                              {
                                  model.Id(c => c.Id);
                                  model.Field(c => c.CompanySoldTo).Editable(true);
                                  model.Field(c => c.CompanyDistributionChannel).Editable(true);
                                  model.Field(c => c.CompanyDivision).Editable(true);
                                  model.Field(c => c.CompanyPlant).Editable(true);
                                  model.Field(c => c.CompanySalesOrg).Editable(true);
                              })
            )
            .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanySoldTo).Title("Sold To");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyDistributionChannel).Title("Dist. Chan.");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanyPlant).Title("Plant");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.CompanySalesOrg).Title("Sales Org");
                      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Title(("Edit SAP Info."));
                  })
                    .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Detail"))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
                )
            </script>
            <script>
                function dataBound() {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone experiences this issue in the future, the problem was actually in my custom pop-up editor template.  I had a data validation message on one of the input boxes set as "Please enter your account #".  The "#" was being interpreted as a template by Kendo.  I escaped the # and then was able to get it to successfully load.